# SPOSiteSwap : Errors: [1]; Warnings: [0]; Details: The Site is not a communications site or it has the classic publishing feature enabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell

> SPOSiteSwap: Errors: [1]; Warnings: [0];
>
> Details: The Site is not a communications site or it has the classic publishing feature enabled.

Trying to replace the communication site with modern team site but unable to replace with the above error. Classic publishing feature is not enabled in modern team site.

Please Suggest.

Comment: Are you handling a communication site or team site?

Comment: I have root site as communication site , trying to replace it with modern team site , both are not hub or group associated, facing this issue on this command

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations of the Site Swapping Procedure**

> - The site you select as the new root site must be a communication site (SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0) or a modern team site that isn't connected
>   to a Microsoft 365 group (STS#3) and where the publishing feature has
>   never been activated.
> - The current root site can't be connected to a Microsoft 365 group.
> - When you replace the root site, both the current site and the new site can't be hub sites or associated with a hub. If either site is a
>   hub site, unregister it as a hub site, replace the root site, and then
>   re-register the site as a hub site. If either site is associated with
>   a hub, disassociate the site, replace the root site, and then
>   reassociate the site. Learn how to manage hubs in the new SharePoint
>   admin center
> - Replacing the root site with another site replaces the entire site collection with the new site collection. If your current root site has
>   subsites, they'll be archived.
> - The site you select as the new root site must be within the same domain as the current root site.

Source: [Modernize your root site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site)